# Going from a primitive class to a wrapper class

Tags: java, class, wrapper, primitive, boxing

Is there a generic way in Java of going from a primitive class like `int.class` to a wrapper class `Integer.class` given a `java.lang.Class` object for which `#isPrimitive()` return `true`?

Some context: I'm writing an `InvocationHandler` for an interface proxy. At then end of the `#invoke` method I want to make sure the object I'm about to return matches the return type of the interface method. Normally I would use `Method.getReturnType().cast(Class)` however this doesn't work for primitive types because `int.class.cast(Class)` doesn't accept `java.lang.Integer` instances.

Is there a generic way of doing this other than manually mapping every primitive class?

***Edit:***

I'm not looking to create a new or default instance. I just need the class to do a type check. Here's a code snipped to explain the issue:

```
class ProblemDemo implements InvocationHandler {

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        Object returnValue = doGenericProxyStuff();
        return method.getReturnType().cast(returnValue);
    }

    private Object doGenericProxyStuff() {
        // generic code there that always returns a wrapper
    }

}
```

The `#cast()` is there to ensure the types match. However in the case when the method has return type `int` this fails. Because `method.getReturnType()` returns `int.class` and not `Integer.class`. `#doGenericProxyStuff()` has to return an `Integer` instance because `#invoke()` has to return a wrapper type for primitive types. I need a way to go from `int.class` to `Integer.class`.

Comment: Some code snippets would really help..

Comment: I had a similar problem, I wrote my own mapping: https://github.com/dperezcabrera/sconf4j/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dperezcabrera/sconf4j/factories/FluentInterfaceFactory.java